Userid on ext2 not same as userid on ext4
I have an installed ubuntu 23.04 on a flashdrive partition type ext2. I’m migrating everything to another ubuntu installation on an ext4 filesystem on another device. On both systems I have userid stuart 1000 group 1000. Booting from the new installation, I cannot read any files owned by me on the ext2 device, though permissions may be 777. If I try to do any kind of operation on those files, I get “permission denied” or “input/output error”. Even “ls -l” gives “input/output error (though it displays the proper result”). Stunningly, I cannot read those files with sudo, either! If I boot to the ext2 device, those files are readable just fine. I am a sudoer on both systems. Partition Manager shows the ext2 partition correctly on the ext4 installation; “mount” shows it mounted as ext2 ro. What’s the problem here?
-Stuart
Followup:I believe the problem was transitory and electrical: I shutdown the system, removed the errant device and moved it to another port -viola! Files are readable as normal. I’ve migrated off the device, so the problem needn’t recur. Thanks for your time.
-Stuart

As you said you put the file permission to chmod 777, it shouldn't be a permission problem. What happens when you use a file manager? Can you see the files? Do you notice anything strange if you right-click on an icon a select "properties"?

Please [edit] your question and tell us how you are mounting the ext2 device. Also tell us basic things like your Ubuntu version, show instead of describing the output of ls -l, as well as the exact error (the wording is important).

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Are you sure you downloaded/installed Ubuntu 23.04 as stated?  That release reached EOL back in January 2024, it's supported release-upgrade path ended when 23.10 went EOL earlier this year too.  If that's the release you're using, I suggest you keep your system offline.
